# Regex extraction from Right to Left

Tags: regex, pcre, splunk

I have some data where I like to extract data from right to left.   Sample data

```
1,4,34
5,15
22
```

Expected output:

```
One=34  Two=4  Three=1
One=15  Two=5
One=22
```

This is as far as I have got with my regex experience.

```
(?:(?<three>\d+),)?(?:(?<two>\d+),)?(?<one>\d+)$
```

But this gives :

```
One=34  Two=4  Three=1
One=15  Three=5
One=22
```

So it fails when there are only two extraction.  Any good idea?
PS I do not have any revers tools

Comment: Well no matter what you do, regex are evaluated LTR.

Comment: What is the problem when you have a down vote ?  Maybe your question was "not clear"  (or anything else in "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful") to the person who clicked the downvote..

Comment: I think this question is crystal clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the first 2 groups optional as a whole:

```
^(?:(?:(?<three>\d+),)?(?<two>\d+),)?(?<one>\d+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:(?<three>\d+),)?` Optionally capture 1+ digits in group "three" and match a comma
  - `(?<two>\d+),` Capture 1+ digits in group "two" and match a comma
- `)?` Close the non capture group
- `(?<one>\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group "one"
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UM38tI/1)

Comment: Thanks.  Event better :)    Using Debuggex, you even see how it works:
https://www.debuggex.com/r/5m3CH-weKEdZZMIe

Comment: It is also possible to avoid the nesting of groups by using non-greedy quantifiers and by letting the backtracking do the work. https://regex101.com/r/JTiKQF/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Great example string :-) Looks promising, let me study this gem.

Answer (score 1):

`^((?:(?<three>\d+),)(?:(?<two>\d+),)|(?:(?<two2>\d+),)?)(?<one>\d+)$` is the only potential solution I can think of, but since capture groups must all have different names, you end up with 2 "two" with different names.

Comment: I will accept this, since I can use coalesce to merge two or two2 to two.  Thanks.   Not user why some give -1 vote one this.  I was looking for a solution to a problem and now that regex goes from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

Naming groups in the reverse order is ok.
If you're looking for matching in the reverse order, this is a direct way.

This is a template regex that can be expanded as needed and will match left to
right (LTR) in a string from the last to the first in ascending group order.

This removes post processing steps.

Example, these strings produce these matching arrays:

```
1,4,34 => [34,4,1]
5,15 => [15,5]
22 => [22]
```

https://regex101.com/r/uo04VM/1

```
^(?=(?&D_n){0,2}(\d+)$)(?=(?:(?&D_n){0,1}(\d+)(?&n_D)$)?)(?=(?:(\d+)(?&n_D){2}$)?).+$(?(DEFINE)(?<D_n>\d+[^\d\r\n]+)(?<n_D>[^\d\r\n]+\d+))
```

Expanded

```
^
(?=
   (?&D_n){0,2}
   ( \d+ )                       # (1)
   $
)
(?=
   (?:
      (?&D_n){0,1}
      ( \d+ )                       # (2)
      (?&n_D) $
   )?
)
(?=
   (?:
      ( \d+ )                       # (3)
      (?&n_D){2} $
   )?
)
.+ $
(?(DEFINE)
   (?<D_n> \d+ [^\d\r\n]+ )      # (4)
   (?<n_D> [^\d\r\n]+ \d+ )      # (5)
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did use some time to understand how it works and what you have done.  It has three different match that matches the whole line using positive lookahead that does not consume the line. You do also use subpattern that saves you from wringing the same stuff various times.

Comment: @Jotne - Matching the whole line is a place holder. It's a visual reference and tells the engine to stop, no more matches allowed on this line.

Answer (score 0):

You want a variable-list of field *names* extracted from delimited data in reverse order?

How many entries could you *possibly* have? Three? Five? Two hundred seventy four?

Are you trying to do this at search time (ie in SPL you are writing/running), or in props.conf?

If you are trying to do this at search time, I would not try to use a regular expression at all - use [`split()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/MultivalueEvalFunctions#split.28.26lt.3Bstr.26gt.3B.2C.26lt.3Bdelim.26gt.3B.29) (or [`makemv`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/makemv)) and [`mvindex()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/MultivalueEvalFunctions#mvindex.28.26lt.3Bmv.26gt.3B.2C.26lt.3Bstart.26gt.3B.2C.26lt.3Bend.26gt.3B.29) (with negative indexing) to find the items you want:

```
...
| eval mvlist=split(delimited_field,",")
...
| eval three=mvindex(mvlist,-3)
...
```

Comment: Some other ideas are here: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Enterprise/Reverse-the-order-of-values-for-a-multivalue-field/m-p/572847

Comment: That will not work.  I need first hit to be always the last number, even if its `22` or `2/32` or `2/1/42` .  Result form this should be 22 32 or 42.  Then next hit should be second last hits, so 32 and 1.  (Nothing from the first number.) and third hit will show only 2 from `2/1/42`.  If number was swapped around no problem, since regex will hit always form left to right.

Comment: @Jotne - What about splitting the field on the comma and then selecting from the bottom of the list to the top "will not work"?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using regex from right to left, I found a way to revers the string.

Sed by it self seem to have a limit to 9 numbered back references.

```
echo "AbCdEfG" | sed  -r 's/(.)(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?/\7\6\5\4\3\2\1/'
GfEdCbA
```

But sed splunk does not have this limit (nor that I need so many) so

```
| makeresults 
| eval test="abcdefghijkl"
| rex mode=sed field=test "s/(.)(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?(.)?/\12\11\10\9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1/"
```

gives: `test=lkjihgfedcba`

Then using regex from left to right works fine.